# how to get input through System.in?

Tags: java, input

I am a beginner Java programmer, and I use this [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

In the [I/O from the Command Line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) page, it uses `InputStreamReader cin = new InputStreamReader(System.in);` to get user input from the command line. But when I try to use it, nothing happens. I have a very simple program, and it's just to test whether this works, but it doesn't.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestInput {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        if(cin.equals("jon")) {
            System.out.println("hello, jon.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("hello, guest.");
        }
    }
}
```

It just says, "hello, guest" and exits, without letting me input anything.

I'm assuming this is supposed to work similar to `System.console`, but if this isn't what it's supposed to be like, please tell me.

What is wrong with my code?

thanks for any answers.

**EDIT**

From the edits I'm getting, I suppose I have to use `cin.readline()` to actually read the input.

I got my program to work. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try{
   BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String name= cin.readLine();

    if(name!=null && name.equals("jon")) {
        System.out.println("hello, jon.");
   } else {
        System.out.println("hello, guest.");
   }
 }catch(IOException e){

 }
```

Comment: why are you using `BufferedReader()`?

Comment: The Java.io.BufferedReader class reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read the input:

```
if(cin.readLine().equals("jon")) {  // or "jon".equals(...) to handle null
```

(See [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29))

You will also have to handle the potential `IOException` with a [`try`-`catch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

With `cin.equals("jon")`, you are testing if the `BufferedReader` object `cin` is *itself* equal to the string `"jon"`, which is clearly false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use, `cin.readLine()`

[Oracle Docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cin.readLine().equals("jon"))
```

Also, you need to handle the IOException